# How to predict a series of 2d data in sequence

Tags: scikit-learn, tensorflow, time-series

I've been struggling with this for long time. My question is this:

I have a series of 2d data, e.g.,

```
d1 = [1,1,0;0,0,0;0,0,0]
d2 = [0,0,0;1,1,0;0,0,0]
```

d1 corresponds to time T1 (e.g., 10:00), d2 corresponds to time T2 (e.g., 11:00). Now I'm trying to predict how the array looks like at T3 (e.g., 12:00). For example, if everything works:

```
d3 = [0,0,0;0,0,0;1,1,0];
```

Is it possible to use sklearn or tensorflow to do so ? If not, could you pls indicate which way I should go ? Thank you very much

Comment: I understand that we can easily pick up the time series prediction if d1/d2/d3 has only one value, but seems if they come with higher dimensions things become different ?

Answer (score 0):

Convert the data to positions probably will make training easier. Ex. d1=[0, 1], d2=[2,3]. In this case train with d1 (converted) as input and d2 (converted) as label. You will have to train for wrap around if you support such case.